# Code repetition (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, repeat

I'm trying not to repeat code. Is there any way to get this working so I don't have to write out the code three times for the three people? Forgive my ignorance: I'm a beginner.

```
$c1 = "Rufus T Firefly";
$c2 = "Chicolini";
$c3 = "Pinky";

for ($i=1; $i<=3; $i++){
  $result = mysqli_query($dbc, ' SELECT * FROM voters WHERE choice = "'. $c($i).'" ');
  //create table...
}
```

Comment: Ah, use an array right? Silly me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`IN()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in)

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM voters WHERE choice IN('Rufus T Firefly', 'Chicolini', 'Pinky')"
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $sql);
```

Now no loops or arrays needed (to generate your query).

Comment: Generating the `IN()` clause dynamically with parameter place-holders is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: I'm trying to create three different tables depending on which person was chosen. This method creates one table with everything in it...

Comment: You can easily loop through these results and determine which table a user goes into using `ORDER BY` and some PHP logic.